# multiple definition of main

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, automake

I’m trying to create .`/configure` + `make` set for building C codes in following structure by using `autotools`. `drive.c` uses function in `mylib.c`

```
[mylib]
 +mylib.c
 +mylib.h
[src]
 +drive.c
```

More details are here.

[mylib.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main(){
    mylib();
    return 0;
}
void
mylib(void)
{
  printf ("Hello world! I AM mylib \n");
}
```

[mylib.h]

```
void mylib(void);
```

[drive.c]

```
#include <mylib.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  mylib();
  return 0;
}
```

Actually I’ve given `main()` both `mylib.c` and `drive.c`.

If I `make` them on CentOS process is noremally finished however If I `make` them on MINGW an error message `multiple definition of`main'` is shown

How can I `make` them on MINGW even if they have multiply have `main()`?

And those followings are config files for autotools.

[confiugre.ac]

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([libmylib], [1], [admin@localhost])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([mylib/mylib.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
LT_INIT
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([mylib/Makefile
                 src/Makefile
                 Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

[Makefile.am]

```
SUBDIRS = mylib src
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

[Makefile.am@src]

```
bin_PROGRAMS = drive
drive_SOURCES = drive.c
LDADD = ../mylib/libmylib.la
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I../mylib
```

[Makefile.am@mylib]

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylib.la
libmylib_la_SOURCES = mylib.c
include_HEADERS = mylib.h
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have multiple main(). What is the problem you are trying to solve by having multiples of it?

Comment: If there is some C code potentially could be shared library that I’ve made or someone’s made. At the first I copy it from original file and then edit its source to remove main for avoiding multiple main. 
I think I can short cut this process if I can compile multiple main().
Also think debug scene, It’s easier to tiny test for some kind of library. If it has main() I can compile it as executable for tiny test. After testing it I can compile it as shared library.

Comment: If I can’t’compile then on CentOS I haven’t asked this question I would have discarded this idea. But I’ve been able to compile within multiple main on CentOS.That why I want to know how to compile same way on MINGW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing things, the idea of having multiple main() is fundamentally wrong. Libraries never ever contain a main() function.

(With the exception of Windows DLLs that contain a DllMain, but that means something different.)

If you want to provide a test case for your library, you make the test case as a *separate* project which includes the library. The test code should not be inside the library itself, neither should main().

Also, I very much doubt you are able to build a program with several function definitions that have the same name, be it main() or something else. If you believe you have managed this, I would either suspect that you haven't linked the files correctly, or that the linker is crap.